# Why can't I use DynamicResource with DataGridColumn.CellStyle

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, dynamicresource, datagridcolumn

So, for example I have some MVVM WPF application with simple model:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string F1 { get; set; }
    public string F2 { get; set; }
}
```

and simple view model that creates 3 rows:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyObject> Objects { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Objects = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>
            {
                new MyObject{F1 = "V1",F2 = "B1"},
                new MyObject{F1 = "V2",F2 = "B2"},
                new MyObject{F1 = "V3",F2 = "V3"}
            };
    }
}
```

And in view I have a `DataGrid` with manually defined columns and for each column I set `CellStyle`. Both styles defined in `Window.Resources` block. But for first column, I use `StaticResource` and for the second `DynamicResource`

View XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication12.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" x:Name="WholeWindow">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="BaseCellClass" TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=WholeWindow, Path=ViewModel.Objects}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding F1}" Header="F1" CellStyle="{StaticResource BaseCellClass}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding F2}" Header="F2" CellStyle="{DynamicResource BaseCellClass}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

So the problem is: in the second column, the resource doesn't get applied to the column.

[image: see second column]

Comment: This looks like the expected behaviour to me? Can you clarify what you feel the problem is?

Comment: The problem is that `CellStyle` is a `DependencyProperty`, but when I try to use binding in it, it fails to work. Clearly they've made it `DependencyProperty` for a reason.

Comment: What happens if you move the BaseCellClass style to your Application resources (or another location that is loaded before the `Window` is initialized)?

Comment: Using DynamicResources on a DataGrid is not a great idea, StaticResource are retrieved only once by the referencing element and used for entire life of the resource. DynamicResource are acquired every time the referenced object is used. The performance hit on a Datagrid with many Items would be quite big, also if you are declaring the Resource in the same file there is no need to use DynamicResource

Comment: Fully agree with the @sa_ddam213. In your case you need to use `Converters`, `DynamicResource` is useless.

Comment: Yeah, `StaticResource` will work fine ofc, but in my case I need to use `DynamicResource`. This code sample I made just to illustrate the problem. In our real application the goal is to use `DynamicResource` to be able to change styles on the fly. Anyway I think this is impossible with basic realization of DataGridColumn and I looking for other ways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create resources for the properties in your `DataGridCell` `Style` and then reference them as a `DynamicResource` within the `Style` definition:

Based on your example it would look like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ForegroundBrush" Color="Blue"/>

    <Style x:Key="BaseCellClass" TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource ForegroundBrush}" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=WholeWindow, Path=ViewModel.Objects}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding F1}" Header="F1" CellStyle="{StaticResource BaseCellClass}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding F2}" Header="F2" CellStyle="{StaticResource BaseCellClass}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

The resources would of course be located in separate resource files.

Comment: Thank you. Your soulution works fine. But in the question I forgot to say that I need a way to derive styles like in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490264/dynamicresource-for-style-basedon

Comment: Anyway I'll mark your answer as right and post my own solution where I use little service for that

Answer (score 1):

I found solution with using a little service. In few words I write in xaml this code:

```
<wpfApplication12:DataGridColumnDynamicStyleService TargetGrid="{Binding ElementName=Grid}">
        <wpfApplication12:DataGridColumnDynamicStyleService.ColumnStyles>
            <wpfApplication12:DataGridColumnStyleBinding ColumnTag="C1" DynamicStyle="{DynamicResource BaseCellClass}" />
        </wpfApplication12:DataGridColumnDynamicStyleService.ColumnStyles>
    </wpfApplication12:DataGridColumnDynamicStyleService>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=WholeWindow, Path=ViewModel.Objects}" x:Name="Grid">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding F1}" Header="F1" wpfApplication12:DataGridColumnDynamicStyle.ColumnTag="C1" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding F2}" Header="F2" wpfApplication12:DataGridColumnDynamicStyle.ColumnTag="C2" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Here, as you can see, I use attached property ColumnTag to identify columns. And I create a service control that defines styles for columns and set target datagrid as `TargetGrid`
If you want to see all the code, here is the link to the solution on [google drive](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3YUNOHjOrdBcVhJY0NOYko2YmM/edit?usp=sharing)